# Show there exists a unique (up to isomorphism) non-cyclic abelian group of order $p^2q$ where p and q are prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I think the way to approach showing it is noncyclic is to consider $\mathbb{Z}_p + \mathbb{Z}_p + \mathbb{Z}_q$.  Then its non-cyclic because the subgroups would have to have order p, q, p^2, or pq so it can't have a subgroup of order $p^2q$.

**I have no idea though how to show that it exists or is unique.**

I also need to find the orders of all cyclic subgroups.  My instinct is to just compute these directly.  Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existence, you can show that $\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_q$ cannot be generated by one element: Every element has order at most $pq$ and $pq<p^2q$. Hence, it is non-cyclic. It is clearly an abelian group because it is the sum of abelian groups.

For the uniqueness, you can use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Regarding the orders of the cyclic subgroups, recall that Lagrange's Theorem states that the order of a subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ must divide the order of $G$. So the subgroups of a group of order $p^2q$ have orders: $1,p,p^2,q,pq,p^2q$. Consider each of these separately:

- $1$: The trivial group is cyclic.
- $p$ and $q$: A group of prime order is cyclic.
- $p^2$: $\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the only subgroup of order $p^2$, but it is non-cyclic.
- $pq$: $\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_q$ is cyclic if $p$ and $q$ are coprime.
- $p^2q$: The only subgroup of order $p^2q$ is the group itself, which is non-cyclic.

Comment: Thank you! Now, how would I go about finding the orders of all cyclic subgroups?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups directly implies that an abelian group of order $p^2q$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_q$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}+\mathbb{Z}_q$. And it must be the former because it is noncyclic.

Comment: yeah, but wouldn't like $\mathbb{Z}_5$ be a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for p>5?

Comment: Only if $5\mid p$ by Lagrange's theorem. But if $p$ is a prime and $p>5$, then $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is never a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: ok so they have to have orders $p, p^2, q$, or $p^2q$.  So how do we know that the subgroups of order $\neq p^2q$ aren't cyclic?

Comment: I edited my answer. Does this help?

Comment: yes very much so! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a subgroup $H$ of order $p^2$ and a $L$ subgroup of order $q$, $H\cap L=\{1\}$, this implies that $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times L$, if $H=\mathbb{Z}/p^2$, then $G$ is cyclic, if not $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/p$. You deduce that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/q$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ cyclic though?

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about finding the orders of all cyclic subgroups?